# how to pass values dynamically using c# code in jquery?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, visual-studio

How to pass values dynamically in c# code using jquery.

I am developing a timepicker control using jQuery in Visual Studio.NET. I pass values static its working fine but how to pass values dynamically any one knows please tell me.

Comment: I have no clue what you are trying to do and I think I am not the only one. Jquery is a client-side javascript library. It has nothing to do with the code running server side (C#)

Comment: explain it more, what r u trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean by passing dynamically, but maybe you can try using a hiddenfield control, to store the value in it. So, every time you change the timepicker you update the hiddenfield's value. Like,

```
$('[id$=hiddenfieldId]').val()=$("#datepicker").datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yyyy'})
```